# Update Notification counter using SignalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using SignalR 1.1.3 to make a live notification in my asp.net mvc 4 project. I'm able to append a new message in the message box but I'm unable to update the new message counter. Here are my codes for updating new message counter.

**jQuery Script**

```
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        var notifyVal = $('.notification-red').val();
        var newVal = notifyVal + 1;
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function () {
            $('#newItem').append(
                '<span class="notification-red">' + newVal + '</span>');
        };
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#btnSend').click(function () {
                chat.server.send();
            });
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="newItem" class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                @{
                    int count = 0;   
                 }
                @foreach (var item in MsgList)
                {
                    if (Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status).ToString() == "Unread")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    <span class="notification-red">@count</span>
                }
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What happens here is whenever I send a message from other side, instead of updating the counter number, a new counter appends. How can I update only the number for every click by SignalR?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$('#newItem').append('<span class="notification-red">' + newVal + '</span>');
```

to something like:

```
$('.notification-red').html(newVal);
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Nothing has updated! I actually tried this way before!

Comment: then there is more to the story then, haven't worked with SingalR, but i know what it is, are you sure, your singalR stuff is right? as it seems like its not being  called then... also are you not able to upgrade to the latest singalR?

Comment: I'm using VS2012 & to setup SignalR 2, I've to take some more hassles for it which I don't have time for it. Besides, I'm only using it to make a live update notifications for just 1 page, so version shouldn't be a matter. And please read my post again carefully, I've mentioned that new message are updating successfully so its pretty obvious that my SignalR setup is ok.

Comment: yes but if $('.notification-red').html("new value"); does not work... then clearly it doesnt?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have this markup for dispalying the counter:

```
<span id="notificationCounter"></span>
```

Now as soon as data is ready you can increment the counter:

```
chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function () {
    $('#notificationCounter').html(parseInt($('#notificationCounter').html(), 10) + 1);
};
```